# Construct an instance of a concrete type of a generic, using reflection at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Consider the following class:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
   public T Argument;                
}
```

And a second class that references and uses the GenericClass:

```
public class ClientClass
{
    GenericClass<T> genclass = new GenericClass<T>();
}
```

My problem is that I don't know the type of T at compile time. I am using reflection during runtime to obtain the type of T. Is it possible somehow to use a parametrized expression while instantiating the `GenericClass`?

Comment: Have you considered adding a restriction on T, where T : IMyInterface. That way you won't need to rely on reflection.

Comment: @Ingenu Not for use, but he would still need a concrete type to instantiate his class to include the proper T.

Comment: Yeap I m afraid that David is right

Comment: @DavidPfeffer Well, adding T: new() will allow you to call `new T()`.

Comment: @Ingenu You would only be able to call `new T()` inside of `GenericClass<T>`. Outside, `T` has no defined meaning. Either way it won't help him directly manipulate his open generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to use reflection to build the actual type for which you're looking.

You first need to get the open generic, by using the `typeof` operator:

```
var openType = typeof(GenericClass<>);
```

[Next, you need to build the specific generic you want.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) Say your desired type T is stored in a variable, `type`:

```
var closedType = openType.MakeGenericType(type);
```

[Finally, use reflection to create an instance of that type.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(closedType);
```

As noted by xanatos in the comments, however, you should be aware that this results in a member of type `object`. To be able to manipulate the object without reflection, you have two choices.

1. You can create a parent class, `GenericClass`, from which `GenericClass<T>` derives, and include methods on it that are common to all. (i.e. `GenericClass` contains members that don't need to use `T`.
2. As Ingenu had mentioned in the comments on the question, you can create an interface `IInterface`, and then add a restriction on `T`, `where T : IInterface`. Then, you can cast `instance` to `GenericClass<IInterface>` and manipulate it that way. Obviously, `type` must implement `IInterface` in this case.

You can of course also just keep the `object` reference and manipulate it using reflection only, or use `dynamic` to late-bind any method calls -- this uses reflection under the hood, however.

Comment: +1 And then discover that you can't use it without reflection :-) And you can't even pass it around without reflection or casting to object. It's a sad sad world. You should write `object closeType` to make it evident.

Comment: Thnx for your reply I ll investigate it and maybe get back to you for further explanation :)

Comment: @xanatos Good idea. I've updated the code and added some more helpful hints.

Comment: @panipsilos If I've solved your question, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. And, welcome to StackOverflow!